# how to control the order of groups in a vega-lite stacked bar chart

Tags: vega-lite

Given a stacked bar chart such as in this example: https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/examples/vega-lite/stacked_bar_weather

I want to control the order of the items in the aggregation so that, for example, 'fog' comes at the bottom, with 'sun' next etc. Is that possible?

The reason for this is I have one type that is much larger than the others. I want this to appear at the bottom, then control the domain to 'cut off' most of that section.

Thanks

Comment: note: I can see they come out in alphabetical order by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the stack order via the `order` encoding: see https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/stack.html#sorting-stack-order

Unfortunately, this only allows sorting by field value, rather than by an explicit order as you want here. The workaround is to use a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) to turn your explicit order into a field ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOcNZkFx+AdxP042ylAjEQAXyWZtSWRABmbbQhoANqgUEiCUAyCanD6NLLKcAAebD4AFEEA5BAMspkKAASZfmT5RcraNABeVeZlmZ7x9RCybJaZALqFqpgMCJTWavDaAJSKIEgQ+v6J2q5dIMjaANb6TEhzSnCyUGzK8WRooElHIJg0CHAAqrJ0+ghy9OM+NHCCyvo9se4Anjix6Bm8XC4yQSRoU00Zzo5n0AFlHjACqkCrYCj8THMXG4QD9TkgyGRtHxMACQLtcphxpg-mSAI4MLzndTnUiuJS7QT+U4vN4fdCDWybM60-StBDAvRKaDhAGgZRsZDxYIgHLyJQlcYVaq1b4gRrq1WtSwgBaeWRkAFBEAAYjgAHZ1gBWABM4xtUHtns97qQcE9cAAHO6AIw+e2OsTugCcYgAbI6Ph0ceZLQlTszYegAOo2Yao0XYpQzOw817vabaWbU0WAquS1zYoA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "indexof(['sun', 'fog', 'drizzle', 'rain', 'snow'], datum.weather)",
      "as": "order"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": {"title": "Month of the year"}
    },
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "weather",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["sun", "fog", "drizzle", "rain", "snow"],
        "range": ["#e7ba52", "#c7c7c7", "#aec7e8", "#1f77b4", "#9467bd"]
      },
      "legend": {"title": "Weather type"}
    },
    "order": {"field": "order", "type": "ordinal"}
  }
}
```

[image]